# Distribution incoming account mail to multiple server email from LAN

Tags: email, proxy, gateway, extend

I have problem with extend multiple backend server email from LAN. How to distribution mutliple email account incomming from WAN to exactly multiple server email from LAN. Server email is independency.
I was search email server proxy, email gateway but nothing can do it.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use shared email domain(s)? [One email domain served by multiple mailbox servers]

Comment: One email domain served by multiple mailbox servers => Yes, I want extend mailbox servers to no limit with one email domain.

Comment: Do you want solution for Unix/Linux or MS Windows? Linux => Which is your prefered MTA/SMTP server? Is list of the email addresses pretty stable?

Comment: Do you want solution for Unix/Linux or MS Windows? Linux => Which is your prefered MTA/SMTP => I use SmartMail on window server 2019.
Is list of the email addresses pretty stable? => List of Email addresses will increase time by time. If a old mailbox server is full, new email addresses will be create on new mailbox server

Comment: My experience is limited to make "classic" Unix/Linux SMTP servers deliver something like what you want.

Comment: hi AnFi,
Do you have solution on Linux SMTP for extend unlimited mailbox server. I think Gmail have private solution to extend very large server and email address.

Comment: Looks like a valid case for Cyrus Murder (which is a distributed IMAP service https://www.cyrusimap.org/imap/reference/admin/murder/murder.html ). But beware, ANY such solution is costly to build and maintain.